# control-m schedule job from last working day to last calendar day of a month

Tags: control-m

I want to run a control-m job daily from the last working day of month to the last calendar day of a month.

Suppose there is a calendar defined in control-m for working dates 26th, 27th, 28th on September, then the job will run on these days 28-Sep, 29-Sep and 30-Sep.

May I know how to schedule it in control-m?

Answer (score 1):

Simply -

1. Scheduling Tab - select "Advanced Scheduling" from the drop-down.
2. Under Days of Month select the tick-box "Using Calendar" (and add the name of your calendar).
3. Select the AND button.
4. Select Mon,Tues,etc under the Days of Week.

Once saved you can use the gui to display the planned days or use the ctmrpln utility on the Control-M Server to see the coming year(s).

Answer (score 0):

The only way a figure it out was using a periodic calendar.

You will have to define two periods on the same calendar, the first period will be the working dates and the second will be all the other days by the end of the month.

On the job Scheduling tab

- Schedule: Based on Calendar

  - Relative Calendar Days from Start/End of Week/Period
- Calendar: *Calendar name*

  - Order only on Calendar Days
- Period:

  - Period A, select last day of the period
  - Period B, select all 7 days of the period

[Calendar definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJlZR.png)

[Job Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRq1b.png)

[View Scheduling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWMqU.png)